# Extracting penultimate folder name from path

Tags: python, path, directory

Does anyone know a clever way to extract the penultimate folder name from a given path?

eg folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD
-> I want to know what the name of folderC is, I don't know the names of the other folders and there may be a variable number of directories before folderC but it's always the 2nd to last folder.

everything i come up with seems too cumbersome (eg getting name of folderD using basename and normpath, removing this from path string, and the getting folderC

cheers, -m

Comment: @735Tesla that's not what the OP is asking at all...

Comment: Sorry just reread question and deleted comment

Comment: So what do you want to be the output for your path, `folderC`?

Comment: I want the name of folderC as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yep, there sure is:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.basename(os.path.dirname("folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD"))
'folderC'
```

That is, we find the 'parent directory' of the named path, and then extract the filename of the resulting path from that.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a good way to skip directly to portions within a path in a single call, but what you want can be easily done like so:

```
>>> os.path.basename(os.path.dirname('test/splitting/folders'))
'splitting'
```

Alternatively, if you know you'll always be on a filesystem with `'/'` delineated paths, you can just use regular old `split()` to get there directly:

```
>>> 'test/splitting/folders'.split('/')[-2]
'splitting'
```

Although this is a bit more fragile. The dirname+basename combo works with/without a file at the end of the path, where as the split version you have to alter the index

Comment: unfortunately that is not the case ;)